# WMI performance monitors not available

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wmi

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter (Service Pack) I am trying to query the following counters, but getting the error 'Invalid Query' in `wbemtest.exe`

```
Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory
Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor
```

They are not even turning up in the list of objects! I am new to this, so my apologies if you feel there is information missing. I will make it available as the questions arrive.

The result of:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory"
```

is as follows:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  What's the actual query you are putting using wbemtest?   If you're on a recent Windows, open a PowerShell prompt "as administrator", and run `Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory"` -- does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Backup %windir%\system32\wbem folder, and switch to %windir%\system32\wbem and run **mofcomp Wmi.mof** since this is the MOF file for this Win32_PerfRawData class.
If still fails, consider to rebuild WMI Repository:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/

Comment: Can you expand upon how to rebuild the repository? Please read [answer].